# Bootstrap modal not scrolling horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Adding

```
scrollable={true}
```

will make it scrollable vertically. But it doesn't seem there is a standard way to make it scrollable horizontally?
I have tried a few css-tricks, but none of them makes the modal scrollable.

```
<Modal size="lg" scrollable={true}>
    <div className="modal-header">
        //Have tried to put style directly here but even in DIV or MODAL. Even tried with other directives like overflowX="scrollable"
        <table className="table table-hover table-bordered results" style={{overflowY: 'auto', overflowX: 'auto', maxWidth: '400px'}}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th className="col tableDataCaption">col1</th>
                    <th className="col tableDataCaption">col2</th>
                    <th className="col tableDataCaption">col3</th>
                    ...
                    <th className="col tableDataCaption">col30</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>row1</td>
                    <td>row1</td>
                    <td>row1</td>
                    ...
                    <td>row1</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `overflow` properties to the table but it should be applied to the parent container. In this case to the `modal-header`, which contains the table and should become scrollable when the table overflows. For better practice, you should be adding a `div` after `modal-header` ( also should be using `modal-body` instead ) and adding the `overflow` props to that.